# Refresh Windows 8.1 With USB Installer

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-8-refresh

I have the Windows 8.1 installer ISO contents on a USB flash drive, and I would like to use it to refresh my Windows 8.1 installation which has become corrupted. How can I do this? Whenever I go to the advanced boot option, all it does it prompt with a message asking me to insert either my install CD or recovery media.

Comment: Your flash drive is your installation media.  I assume the installation is corrupt which means its not bootable?

Comment: @Ramhound When I try to run the `setup.exe` file just to see if it works, it opens and then says that it failed to validate the product key. I do not want to do a fresh install, just a recovery, but the recovery is not working.

Comment: Why don't you just use the DISM and sfc /scannow commands?

Comment: @Ramhound I wanted to do it, but it didn't fix the problem, the problem being BitLocker is corrupt.

Comment: If neither command detected any corruption then your installation isn't corrupt.

Comment: @Ramhound The problem has been solved. For some reason the bootable flash drive that I made from the ISO didn't finish successfully the first time around, and as a result it wasn't recognizing it as a valid installer drive. I tried again, and it worked. I was able to refresh my computer. Now all that I have left to do is reinstall of my programs (of which there are millions), restore my backed up appdata folder, and I will be good to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/downloads/rufus-1.4.9.exe) for making any iso bootable,it is very simple to make iso bootable from this tool,its very lightweight tool!

Visit http://rufus.akeo.ie/ for Discription & more!

[image: Rufus]